# How does Laplace transform work when the terms are matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

So I have this Quarter Car Suspension:

[image]
[image]

I’m describing it with a differential equation like so:

[image]

Now there is a sub-problem asking me to prove that the transfer function with output $y=x_1-x_2$ and input $u$ is equal to $G_1(s)$ and that the transfer function with output $y=x_1-x_2$ and input $w$ is equal to $G_2(s)$.

[image]

The elements of the matrices are all there but I’m not sure why they are arranged the way that they are. Is there a formula to follow when the terms in a Laplace transform are matrices?